# Cannot export variable thanks to a script with zsh

Tags: zsh

I have written a script `export-zsh` to set new variables in zsh

```
$ cat export-zsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "export $@">> /root/.zshrc
source /root/.zshrc
```

Errors occur if I run it

```
$export-zsh "a=2"
/root/.zshrc: line 12: setopt: command not found
/root/.zshrc: line 33: bindkey: command not found
/root/.zshrc: line 36: bindkey: command not found
[...]
/root/.zshrc: line 42: modload: command not found
[...]
```

When I execute each command individually, it lead to no errors:

```
$ echo "export a=2">> /root/.zshrc; source /root/.zshrc
$ [ NO ERROR ]
```

when I run `source ~/.zshrc`, there are no errors, so I don't think it should be directly related to my ~/.zshrc content but I give it below to be sure.

---

PS:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP="/home/$USER/Dropbox/.pythonrc"
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
# File:     .zshrc   ZSH resource file                             #
# Version:  0.1.16                                                 #
# Author:   Øyvind "Mr.Elendig" Heggstad <mrelendig@har-ikkje.net> #
#------------------------------------------------------------------#
#------------------------------

# History stuff
#------------------------------
#setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
HISTSIZE=9999999999999999
HISTFILE="/home/nbougach/Dropbox/.histfile"
#setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
#------------------------------
# Variables
#------------------------------
export BROWSER="chromium-browser"
export EDITOR="vim"
#export PAGER="vimpager"
export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/bin:${HOME}/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
#source ~/.b
#-----------------------------
# Dircolors
#-----------------------------
#LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:';
export LS_COLORS

#------------------------------
# Keybindings
#------------------------------
bindkey -v
typeset -g -A key
#bindkey '\e[3~' delete-char
bindkey '\e[1~' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line
#bindkey '\e[2~' overwrite-mode
bindkey '^?' backward-delete-char
bindkey '^[[1~' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^[[5~' up-line-or-history
bindkey '^[[3~' delete-char
bindkey '^[[4~' end-of-line
bindkey '^[[6~' down-line-or-history
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[D' backward-char
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[C' forward-char 
# for rxvt
bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line
bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line
# for gnome-terminal
bindkey "\eOH" beginning-of-line
bindkey "\eOF" end-of-line

#------------------------------
# Alias stuff
#------------------------------
alias ls="ls --color -F"
alias ll="ls --color -lh"
alias spm="sudo pacman"
alias spmc="sudo pacman-color"
alias gr="gvim --remote-silent"
alias vr="vim --remote-silent"

#------------------------------
# ShellFuncs
#------------------------------
# -- coloured manuals
man() {
  env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf "\e[1;31m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf "\e[1;44;33m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf "\e[0m") \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(printf "\e[1;32m") \
    man "$@"
}

#------------------------------
# Comp stuff
#------------------------------
zmodload zsh/complist 
#autoload -Uz compinit
#compinit
zstyle :compinstall filename '${HOME}/.zshrc'

#- buggy
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%U%B%d%b%u'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format '%BSorry, no matches for: %d%b'
#-/buggy

zstyle ':completion:*:pacman:*' force-list always
zstyle ':completion:*:*:pacman:*' menu yes select

#zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}

zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*'   force-list always

zstyle ':completion:*:*:killall:*' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*:killall:*'   force-list always

#- complete pacman-color the same as pacman
compdef _pacman pacman-color=pacman

#------------------------------
# Window title
#------------------------------
case $TERM in
  termite|*xterm*|rxvt|rxvt-unicode|rxvt-256color|rxvt-unicode-256color|(dt|k|E)term)
    precmd () {
      vcs_info
      print -Pn "\e]0;[%n@%M][%~]%#\a"
    } 
    preexec () { print -Pn "\e]0;[%n@%M][%~]%# ($1)\a" }
    ;;
  screen|screen-256color)
    precmd () { 
      vcs_info
      print -Pn "\e]83;title \"$1\"\a" 
      print -Pn "\e]0;$TERM - (%L) [%n@%M]%# [%~]\a" 
    }
    preexec () { 
      print -Pn "\e]83;title \"$1\"\a" 
      print -Pn "\e]0;$TERM - (%L) [%n@%M]%# [%~] ($1)\a" 
    }
    ;; 
esac

#------------------------------
# Prompt
#------------------------------
autoload -U colors zsh/terminfo
colors

autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git hg
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats "%{${fg[cyan]}%}[%{${fg[green]}%}%s%{${fg[cyan]}%}][%{${fg[blue]}%}%r/%S%%{${fg[cyan]}%}][%{${fg[blue]}%}%b%{${fg[yellow]}%}%m%u%c%{${fg[cyan]}%}]%{$reset_color%}"

setprompt() {
  # load some modules
  setopt prompt_subst

  # make some aliases for the colours: (coud use normal escap.seq's too)
  for color in RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE; do
    eval PR_$color='%{$fg[${(L)color}]%}'
  done
  PR_NO_COLOR="%{$terminfo[sgr0]%}"

  # Check the UID
  if [[ $UID -ge 1000 ]]; then # normal user
    eval PR_USER='${PR_GREEN}%n${PR_NO_COLOR}'
    eval PR_USER_OP='${PR_GREEN}%#${PR_NO_COLOR}'
  elif [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]; then # root
    eval PR_USER='${PR_RED}%n${PR_NO_COLOR}'
    eval PR_USER_OP='${PR_RED}%#${PR_NO_COLOR}'
  fi

  # Check if we are on SSH or not
  if [[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT"  ||  -n "$SSH2_CLIENT" ]]; then 
    eval PR_HOST='${PR_YELLOW}%M${PR_NO_COLOR}' #SSH
  else 
    eval PR_HOST='${PR_GREEN}%M${PR_NO_COLOR}' # no SSH
  fi
  # set the prompt
  PS1=$'${PR_CYAN}[${PR_USER}${PR_CYAN}@${PR_HOST}${PR_CYAN}][${PR_BLUE}%~${PR_CYAN}]${PR_USER_OP} '
  PS2=$'%_>'
  RPROMPT=$'${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
}
setprompt

# vim: set ts=2 sw=2 et:
#source ~/.b
setopt HIST_NO_FUNCTIONS

setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS

setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You script is executed by Bash. Reading your `.zshrc` with Bash doesn't work but gets you errors for all the Zsh specific stuff.

Your script runs in its own subshell. As settings, environment variables and such are not exported back to the calling shell ascript will not work here. Use a function instead and put it in your `.zshrc`:

```
export-zsh(){
    echo "export $@">> .zshrc
    source .zshrc
}
```